# Error loading property file (plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war:default-war:package)

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I would like to configure a properties files depending on a profile, either `dev` or `prod`, however the location of the properties file is not correctly constructed. I have found answers to similar issues on SO but none of the those answers have helped resolve this issue.

The error I receive is as follows:

> Error loading property file 'E:\Development\CodeSource\GitHub\myproject\profiles\dev\mongo.properties' (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war:default-war:package)

The actual location of the properties file is:

```
E:\Development\CodeSource\GitHub\myproject\src\main\resources\profiles\dev\mongo.properties
```

So I set the resources location as follows:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Nevertheless it still does not find the properties file.

Here is the entire pom file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>abc.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>projectname</name>
<description>Site Description</description>
<url>http://www.myproject.abc</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.4</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <tomcat-deploy-path>output</tomcat-deploy-path>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    // various dependencies
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>v${project.artifactId}#${project.version}</finalName>
    <filters>
        <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/mongo.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${tomcat-deploy-path}</outputDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

</project>
```

I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the filter files is [relative to the project root, not to `src/main/resources`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). As such, you need to configure it like so:

```xml
<filters>
    <filter>src/main/resources/profiles/${build.profile.id}/mongo.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki. Now fixed. However I am curious as to why the resource directory filtering was not used as the base for the profile location. I found examples that seem to use it this way.

Comment: @Alex Hmm, that'd be weird. Do you have a link to those examples? I don't see how it could work.

Comment: Here is the article I followed: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-profile-specific-configuration-files-with-maven/ also in this example it shows how place holders are replaced with values depending on the profile executed. This doesn't appear to be working either.

Comment: @Alex The way I read it, it doesn't mention to place the filtering files inside `src/main/resources`. It says "The configuration files must be found from the profiles/[profile name] directory." so I interpret it as: relative to the root directory (because almost everything in Maven is relative to the root directory).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Tunaki